# Why does StringFormat have no effect on the binding of my MenuItem.Header?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, string-formatting

All of my 6 samples have "StringFormat" in their binding but none is applied and I'm only getting the value without any formatting.

Any idea what I do wrong?

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding SeriesNearMouse.Count, StringFormat='Series {0}'}">
</MenuItem>

<MenuItem DataContext="SeriesNearMouse">
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <Binding Path="Count" 
                    StringFormat="Series{0:D}test">
        </Binding>
    </MenuItem.Header>

</MenuItem>
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <Binding Path="SeriesNearMouse.Count" 
                    StringFormat="Series{0}">
        </Binding>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>

<MenuItem Header="{Binding SeriesNearMouse.Count, StringFormat='{}Series {0}'}">
</MenuItem>

<MenuItem DataContext="SeriesNearMouse">
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <Binding Path="Count" 
                    StringFormat="{}Series{0:D}test">
        </Binding>
    </MenuItem.Header>

</MenuItem>
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <Binding Path="SeriesNearMouse.Count" 
                    StringFormat="{}Series{0}">
        </Binding>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: @Sheridan, you make me realize that my title wasn't very well choosen. But I prefer the one I just modified because it has no negate (doesn't) and also seems more accurate (better representation of the situation I had). Thanks to help me having better question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is probably not working how you expect because MenuItem.Header is an object, not a string.

Something like this should work, since Run.Text is a string:

```
<MenuItem>
  <MenuItem.Header>
    <Run Text="{Binding SeriesNearMouse.Count, StringFormat='Series {0}', Mode=OneWay}" />
  </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thanks a lots. You are totally right. I won't tell you How much time I loose trying to make that work... But you saved my life :-) !!!!!!! (I could have try a specific converter but it would have been too much, and too specific, for so little).

Comment: Note: If you want to have access keys you need to replace the Run with an AccessText. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11353031/2024413)

Answer (score 28):

**LATE ANSWER**

`Header` is not a string property. It is actually an object property that gets presented in a `ContentPresenter`. In order to pass the string format to the `ContentPresenter`, `MenuItem` provides a `HeaderStringFormat` property:

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding SeriesNearMouse.Count}" HeaderStringFormat="Series {0}">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It should help other persons too. Thumbs up!

Comment: Very informative answer. Out of the very complete documentation by microsoft, how / where could we find documentation / presentation of the rationale behind WPF ? ( As an embedded engineer, WPF is not at the present time my main skill and I always fall in such pitfalls. Fortunately I find almost everything on SO )

Comment: @NGI I think it depends on how much you want to invest. If you need to start on a project fast, probably go through one of the tutorials online and then investigate the details as you go along. If you have the time, I think a better approach would be to pick up one of the popular WPF books. I'd also recommend wpf.2000things.com.